# X-editable Bootstrap PHP database update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am trying to update MySQL table with X-editable (Bootstrap). Problem is - the Database is not getting updated. I have gone through several similar kind of issue in stackoverflow and elsewhere. But couldn't find the solution.

My mysql database has a table named 'paving_variety' with the following three columns:

1. id
2. type
3. publish

My front-end page has a table like the following:

```
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($obj->showAllFromTable('paving_variety') as $variety) {
        extract($variety);
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
            <td class="id"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="xedit_variety" data-name="type" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-url="post_variety_ajax.php"><?php echo $type; ?></a></td>
            <td ><button class="status_change btn btn-default"><?php echo $publish; ?></button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

The javascript file has the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.xedit_variety').editable();
    });
```

The "post_variety_ajax.php" looks like this:

```
<?php
$pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

include 'adminclass.php';

if(!empty($value)) {
    $gar->updateVarietyName($name,$value,$pk);
} else {
    echo "This field is required!";
}
?>
```

The "adminclass.php" has the following code for updating the database:

```
public function updateVarietyName($name,$value,$pk) {
    $query = mysqli_query($this->conn,"UPDATE paving_variety SET $name='$value' WHERE id='$pk'");
}
```

Everything else seems ok, but the database is not getting updated. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks. Placid.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your sever pwn3d. Plus, you are simply assuming everything is going perfectly. Did you check `$query` for boolean false in your update function?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on SQL injection attack. I haven't inserted security enhancing code in this project yet, but I will. Yes I have checked $query and it returns true.

Comment: Then check affected_rows as well. if that's zero, then the query is suceeding, but the where clause isn't matching anything so no records get updated.

Comment: @user2407971 making security an afterthought is a bad idea. You *will* forget something. Just use parameterized queries from the beginning and you don't have to worry about refactoring your entire program down the road.

Comment: Done. But the problem persists.

Comment: Except for security issue, what is the problem in functionality of the code?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally solved the problem. It is as follows:

```
$('.xedit_variety').editable({
    ajaxOptions : {
        type : 'post'
    }
});
```

Hope it helps someone else facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.xedit_variety').editable({
      name: 'type',
      type: 'text',
      url: 'post_variety_ajax.php'
   });
});
```

where you should delete

```
data-name="type"
data-type="text"    
data-url="post_variety_ajax.php"
```

in your editable link.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `$_REQUEST[]` in `post_variety_ajax.php` file it will handle both get and post request.

I found a tutorial of x editable here :- [jQuery X editable plugin](https://www.mycodingtutorials.com/?p=259)